# creating a blog application using ruby on rails. When I try to generate devise I get an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[This is the error I am getting.][1]

I am following Techmake studio video in Youtube https://youtu.be/MCEzxY9BbiU
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o1Tf.png

Comment: Could you add the error as a text, please? Also, it might be helpful if you post some code that you have an issue with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.